# Java program to convert XML file to a new XML file that adheres to KML tag rules, using XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, kml

What would a program of this sort need to do? I know that one method would have to parse in the original file, and after that us XSLT convert the original code to a better form (following KML tag rules). I really need to know how to invoke the XSLT in my Java program.

Comment: well, after you parse the original file, you would then need to generate the output file.

Comment: It depends on what's in your XML file.  XML -> KML may not be a direct mapping depending on the contents.

Comment: It won't be a direct mapping from what I understand. The xml isn't the best written, but I have to work with what I have and convert it to a better xml file. It looks like I can use XSLT for that, but I am not very familiar with XSLT coding.

Answer (score 1):

> What would a program of this sort need to do?

Well, we don't know any details, so all we can say is that it's an XML to XML transformation and that the best language for expressing such transformations is XSLT. Were you asking about how to invoke XSLT from Java? That's easy. Or were you asking how to write the XSLT? That depends on the input and output.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks. Once I get the XSLT document written, I need to know how to implement it with a Java program.